# div's background is different than it's content (same values passed)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Ok, so I have a very strange problem (I'm using next.js).

I'm mapping shuffled array.

```
const otherPoepleData = shuffle(allPeople).filter(item => item.full_slug !== data.full_slug).slice(0, 3)
```

```
{otherPoepleData.map((item, index) =>
  <SpeakerNew data={item} key={item.id} index={index} />
)}
```

To sum up the problem I've put inside SpeakerNew component following code:

```
<div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${image.filename})` }}>
  {image.filename}
</div>
```

And here are the results:

```
<div style="background-image: 
  url(https://something.com/blablaba57674676343zzx.png);">
      https://something.com/blablaba13123123dasdzz.png
</div>
```

The content of the div is 100% correct, however the backgroundImage url is incorrect. Taken from completely other person from array I'm mapping. What coulde be the problem here?

Comment: if you put `console.log(image.filename)` inside SpeakerNew component what do you see ?

Comment: @monesulhaque It's the correct value, if I put onMouseOver in this image it's also correct value

Comment: what do you mean by incorrect value? is it image url of another item inside *otherPoepleData* or it is just a random string? can you provide more info like console logs?

Comment: @Ako yes it's image url of another item inside that array.

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example, it's difficult to help otherwise. Provide what you would need to run this code.